# disable specific single date and multiple dates in angularjs (only datePicker and not dateTimePicker)

Tags: angularjs, datepicker

I want to disable specific dates in the date picker of AngularJS.

I am using AngularJS-bootstrap css for components(angular directives).(ui.bootstrap.datepicker)

i was using the following code:

datePicker.html:

```
          <title>Typehead</title>
          <meta charset="UTF-8">
          <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
          <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
              <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular-animate.js"></script>
            <script src="./ui-bootstrap-tpls-1.2.1.min.js"></script>
          <script src="./datePicker.js"></script>






        </head>

        <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" >

        <style>
          .full button span {
            background-color: limegreen;
            border-radius: 32px;
            color: black;
          }
          .partially button span {
            background-color: orange;
            border-radius: 32px;
            color: black;
          }
        </style>
        <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
            <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

            <h4>Inline</h4>
            <div style="display:inline-block; min-height:290px;">
              <uib-datepicker ng-model="dt" class="well well-sm" datepicker-options="inlineOptions" ></uib-datepicker>
            </div>

            <h4>Popup</h4>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats"  />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

                 <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" is-open="popup3.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open3()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>

              <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup ng-model="dt" is-open="popup2.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                  <span class="input-group-btn">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open2()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                  </span>
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Format: <span class="muted-text">(manual alternate <em>{{altInputFormats[0]}}</em>)</span></label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
              </div>
            </div>

            <hr />
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="setDate(2009, 7, 24)">2009-08-24</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" uib-tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
        </div>



        </body>
```

datePicker.js:

```
            var myApp= angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.dateparser', 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);



             myApp.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



            $scope.today = function() {
                $scope.dt = new Date();
              };
              $scope.today();

              $scope.clear = function() {
                $scope.dt = null;
              };

              $scope.inlineOptions = {
                customClass: getDayClass,
                minDate: new Date(),
                showWeeks: false
              };

              $scope.dateOptions = {
                dateDisabled: disabled,
                formatYear: 'yy',
                maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
                minDate: new Date(),
                startingDay: 1
              };

              // Disable weekend selection
              function disabled(data) {
                var date = data.date,
                  mode = data.mode;
                return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
              }

              $scope.toggleMin = function() {
                $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
                $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
              };

              $scope.toggleMin();

              $scope.open1 = function() {
                $scope.popup1.opened = true;
              };

              $scope.open2 = function() {
                $scope.popup2.opened = true;
              };

                $scope.open3 = function() {
                $scope.popup3.opened = true;
              };

              $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
                $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
              };

              $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
              $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
              $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

              $scope.popup1 = {
                opened: false
              };

              $scope.popup2 = {
                opened: false
              };

              $scope.popup3 = {
                opened: false
              };

              var tomorrow = new Date();
              tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
              var afterTomorrow = new Date();
              afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
              $scope.events = [
                {
                  date: tomorrow,
                  status: 'full'
                },
                {
                  date: afterTomorrow,
                  status: 'partially'
                }
              ];

              function getDayClass(data) {
                var date = data.date,
                  mode = data.mode;
                if (mode === 'day') {
                  var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

                  for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
                    var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0,0,0,0);

                    if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                      return $scope.events[i].status;
                    }
                  }
                }

                return '';
              }



             });
```

the documentation gives me :
dateDisabled (date, mode) - An optional expression to disable visible options based on passing a date and current mode.

i tried long and hard to use it but wasted 5 hours on it. im sure the solution is simple.Can anyone help with the following:

1.How do i use it to disable a single date 
2.Disable multiple dates passed from an array!

any help with working example would be appreciated!

Answer (score 6):

Link the date-disabled attribute to a function that takes two arguments in your scope like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" /> <!-- Other attributes deleted for clarity -->
```

That function will be called for all the visible dates on the calendar. So, you will need to check the date passed against the dates you want to be disabled. For example, the function bellow will disable the dates: 
*March 14, 2016, March 15, 2016 and March 16, 2016*

```
$scope.disabled = function(date, mode){

            var holidays = [
              new Date(2016,2,14),
              new Date(2016,2,15),
              new Date(2016,2,16),
            ]

            var isHoliday = false;
            for(var i = 0; i < holidays.length ; i++) {
              if(areDatesEqual(holidays[i], date)){
                isHoliday = true;
              }
            }

            return ( mode === 'day' && isHoliday );
          };

          function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {

            return date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) === date2.setHours(0,0,0,0)

          }
```

**UPDATE:**

To change the class of a specific date you use the custom-class attribute:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" custom-class="dayClass(date, mode)"/>
```

The **dayClass** function will be called for all the visible dates and return the css class you want to add to that element. For example, the function below will add the class *appointment* to the dates on the appointments array

```
$scope.dayClass = function(date, mode) {

            var appointments = [
              new Date(2016,2,3),
              new Date(2016,2,8),
              new Date(2016,2,22),
            ]

            if (mode === 'day') {

              var dateToCheck = new Date(date);

              for(var i = 0; i < appointments.length ; i++) {
                if(areDatesEqual(appointments[i], dateToCheck)){
                  return 'appointment';
                }
              }
            }
            return '';
          }
```

Then you need to add some style, something like this:

```
.appointment>button {
  color: white;
  background-color: red;
}
```

**UPDATE 2**

To perform an action for specific dates you could use *ng-change* and follow the same approach as before, it could be something like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected()" /> <!-- Other attributes deleted for clarity -->
```

On your controller:

```
$scope.dateSelected = function(){

var appointments = [
  new Date(2016,2,3),
  new Date(2016,2,8),
  new Date(2016,2,22),
];

var dateSelected = new Date($scope.dt);

for(var i = 0; i < appointments.length ; i++) {
  if(areDatesEqual(appointments[i], dateSelected)){
    performAction();
  }
}

};

function performAction(){
  alert("Appointment date selected");
}
```

Here a full example:

```js
var myApp= angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo', ['ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.dateparser', 'ui.bootstrap.datepicker']);



             myApp.controller('DatepickerDemoCtrl', function($scope, $http) {



            $scope.today = function() {
                $scope.dt = new Date();
              };
              $scope.today();

              $scope.clear = function() {
                $scope.dt = null;
              };

              $scope.inlineOptions = {
                minDate: new Date(),
                showWeeks: false
              };

              $scope.dateOptions = {
                  formatYear: 'yy',
                  maxDate: new Date(2020, 5, 22),
                  minDate: new Date(),
                  startingDay: 1
                };

                // Disable weekend selection
                function disabledasda(data) {
                  var date = data.date,
                    mode = data.mode;
                  return mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6);
                }

              $scope.toggleMin = function() {
                $scope.inlineOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate ? null : new Date();
                $scope.dateOptions.minDate = $scope.inlineOptions.minDate;
              };

              $scope.toggleMin();

              $scope.open1 = function() {
                $scope.popup1.opened = true;
              };


              $scope.setDate = function(year, month, day) {
                $scope.dt = new Date(year, month, day);
              };

              $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
              $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];
              $scope.altInputFormats = ['M!/d!/yyyy'];

              $scope.popup1 = {
                opened: false
              };


              var today = new Date();
               
              $scope.holidays = [
                  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),14),
                  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),15),
                  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),16),
              ]
              
              $scope.appointments = [
                  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),3),
                  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),7),
                  new Date(today.getFullYear(),today.getMonth(),20),
              ]
              $scope.disabled = function(date, mode){
              
                var isHoliday = false;
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.holidays.length ; i++) {
                  if(areDatesEqual($scope.holidays[i], date)){
                    isHoliday = true;
                  }
                }

                return ( mode === 'day' && isHoliday );
              };

              function areDatesEqual(date1, date2) {

                return date1.setHours(0,0,0,0) === date2.setHours(0,0,0,0)

              }

              $scope.dayClass = function(date, mode) {

            if (mode === 'day') {

              var dateToCheck = new Date(date);

              for(var i = 0; i < $scope.appointments.length ; i++) {
                if(areDatesEqual($scope.appointments[i], dateToCheck)){
                  return 'appointment';
                }
              }
            }
            return '';
          };

          $scope.dateSelected = function(){



    var dateSelected = new Date($scope.dt);

    for(var i = 0; i < $scope.appointments.length ; i++) {
      if(areDatesEqual($scope.appointments[i], dateSelected)){
        performAction();
      }
    }

  };

  function performAction(){
    alert("Appointment date selected");
  }



             });
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Typehead</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.0-rc.2/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/ui-bootstrap-tpls.min.js"></script>
   
  </head>
  <body ng-app="ui.bootstrap.demo" >
    <style>
      .full button span {
        background-color: limegreen;
        border-radius: 32px;
        color: black;
      }
      .partially button span {
        background-color: orange;
        border-radius: 32px;
        color: black;
      }
      .appointment>button {
        color: white;
        background-color: red;
      }

    </style>
    <div ng-controller="DatepickerDemoCtrl">
      <pre>Selected date is: <em>{{dt | date:'fullDate' }}</em></pre>

      <h4>Popup</h4>
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <p class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  uib-datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="dt" ng-change="dateSelected()"is-open="popup1.opened" datepicker-options="dateOptions" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" alt-input-formats="altInputFormats" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" custom-class="dayClass(date, mode)" />
            <span class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open1()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
            </span>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks sergio Marron! this seems to work! i had searched far and wide on stack overflow for something to start with and had got stuck. But now ive found the solution in ur code.thanks a lot!

Comment: By any chance do you/anyone know to colour specific dates with the choice of my colour?

Comment: Sergio Marron, the code does'nt seem to work in my xampp server! but works on plunker! i dunno how is that so!

Comment: @ClydeDias I updated the answer and included how to add some style. About your server, there must be an issue when comparing the dates, maybe the timezone of your server, but I couldn't say.

Comment: yes done! the problem was with the loading of ui-bootstrap-tpls! i linked it now with: <script src="cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-bootstrap/1.1.2/…; .it wokrs fine now! thank you Sergio Marron! thanks a lot!

Comment: Anytime...glad to help

Comment: i wanted to execute a angular js function on click of certain buttons....i tried to use the similar logic as you used to disable dates and change colours but seem to have got stuck....how do i do it?

Comment: ...yes that helped a lot ! thats exactly what i needed!

Comment: ...i wanted to now disable other date/dates (one or many) on click of a specific date....what i did was i used push function and pushed that date in the holidays array in dateSelected function....but i guess it needs re rendering of calendar? How do i do that? or simply put, disable other date/dates (one or many) on click of a specific date?

Comment: I did define the holidays array inside the disabled function just for demonstration purposes. If you want to add new dates you should define it in your $scope:   $scope.holidays = [];  now on the dateSelected function, which is the one is linked to change event, just push the new date into the $scope.holidays array

Comment: ....how do i start with all the dates disabled and than enable few specific dates that i need to enable?

Comment: ....how do i start with all the dates disabled and than enable few specific dates that i need to enable? also i tried disabling dates with:    $scope.holidays = [
                  new Date(2016,2,14),
                  new Date(2016,2,15),
                  new Date(2016,2,16),
                ]

                var isHoliday = false;
                for(var i = 0; i < $scope.holidays.length ; i++) {
                  if(areDatesEqual($scope.holidays[i], date)){
                    isHoliday = true;
                  }
                } and: